# software for editing 2 images at the same time

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking to find if possible a tool which can take a area screenshot and let me edit it like so:
[image with boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIGMH.png)

however I also want an image like this to be created simultaneously after editing the first image:
[image with frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iqS9.png)

So what I am looking for is a tool which can do the two tasks at the same time and save them as seperate images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Inkscape will help you. Even though Inkscape is for vector graphics. the fill and stroke feature will help you do this easier.

Check this website to install it :
https://inkscape.org

Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o86MLSQHtMg